# How to properly iterate through two columns and pop rows where data matches to new df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns that I wish to iterate through. The idea is to find any row where the item occurs (in either column) and then move that row to a separate dataframe. Example below, words are hard.

df1:

```
fname lname fnameNum lnameNum fnameWeight lnameWeight fname+num lname+num
  A     B     1         1        25         35            A,1      B,1
  X     Z     3         9        2          17            X,3      Z,9
  N     M     8         7        14         15            N,14     M,15
  B     A     1         1        35         25            B,1      A,1
```

The idea is to do the following:

Take the first row, and copy it to a new dataframe

df2:

```
fname lname fnameNum lnameNum fnameWeight lnameWeight fname+num lname+num group
  A     B     1         1        25         35            A,1      B,1    1
```

Then, take the value of `fname+num` and see which lines in the df1 contain an exact match, searching both `fname+num` and `lname+num`.

Once the matches have been made and all of the rows are copied over I wish to delete them from df1. This leaves df2 like so:

```
fname lname fnameNum lnameNum fnameWeight lnameWeight fname+num lname+num group
  A     B     1         1        25         35            A,1      B,1    1
  B     A     1         1        35         25            B,1      A,1    1
```

df1 would look like the following:

```
fname lname fnameNum lnameNum fnameWeight lnameWeight fname+num lname+num
  X     Z     3         9        2          17            X,3      Z,9
  N     M     8         7        14         15            N,14     M,15
```

My goal is to then do the same thing again on the first element of df1, and keep doing so until df1 is effectively empty.

The method that I wrote to try and tackle this:

```
df2.iloc[len(df2)] = df1.iloc[0, :] #get the first row of df1, copy to df2
for row in df1.iterrows():
    for row in df2.iterrows():
        if df2['fname+num'].isin((df1['fname+num' or df1['lname+num'])): 
            df2.loc[len(df2)] = df1.iloc[row]#if there is a match between the df2['fname+num'][0] and any element of any row in df1['fname+num' | 'lname+num'] then copy that entire row from df1 to df2
```

not shown* delete all rows in df1 that exist in df2 (out of scope)

Comment: when you say: "keep doing so until df1 is effectively empty", do you mean everytime adding rows in `df2` or create a separate one each time?

Comment: @Ben.T I mean populate `df2` and drop any rows in `df1` that are present in `df2`

Comment: So I think your problem is more a sorting problem

Comment: @Ben.T Yes more or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to sort your dataframe in a specific way, I would first find the first position of each different value in 'fname+num' and then `map` both column 'fname+num' and 'lname+num', get the `min` over the two columns per row and `sort` with these values:

```
#find order of first occurence of each element of the column fname+num
dict_order = {val:i for i, val in enumerate(df1['fname+num'].drop_duplicates())}

# create the minimun of in a column sort once both 
# fname+num and lanem+num are mapped with the dict_order
df1['to_sort'] = (pd.concat([df1['fname+num'].map(dict_order),
                             df1['lname+num'].map(dict_order)], axis=1)
                   .min(axis=1, skipna=True)) 

#sort by this column, 
df2 = df1.sort_values('to_sort').drop('to_sort', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

and you get for `df2`:

```
  fname lname  fnameNum  lnameNum  fnameWeight  lnameWeight fname+num  \
0     A     B         1         1           25           35       A,1   
1     B     A         1         1           35           25       B,1   
2     X     Z         3         9            2           17       X,3   
3     N     M         8         7           14           15      N,14   

  lname+num  
0       B,1  
1       A,1  
2       Z,9  
3      M,15
```

Edit with expectation of the comment, I would say you should change the `dict_order`, where all the connection between elements are creating thanks to [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53677003/9274732)

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
all_tuples=tuple(zip(df['fname+num'],df['lname+num']))
G.add_edges_from(all_tuples)
dict_order = { val:i for i, vals in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)) for val in vals}
```

and then the same rest of code

Comment: @MaxB add `copy()` and remove the `drop` because this column would have your group, even if it may not be consecutive numbers in the real data: `df2 = df1.sort_values('to_sort').reset_index(drop=True).copy()`

Comment: I think there may be an issue with how it is grouping. For example, on my end I am seeing `A,1` appear in different groups, when every `A,1` and item related to `A,1` should be in the same group

Comment: @MaxB it depends when the first `A,1` is in your column fname+num, the way you explained your problem does not say that same element must be in a same group. In the example you gave, what would be the result according to you if you change `B,1` in the last row by `Z,9` ?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear in asking the question. If `B,1` in the last row were changed to `Z,9` then the line containing `X,3`-`Z,9` would be in the same group as the initial `A,1`

Comment: @MaxB oh so this a different problem then. this method may be complicated to change to fit this expectation.

Comment: I appreciate the help you have offered up to this point. Asking the question correctly is always a hurdle in itself sometimes.

Comment: @MaxB indeed :) I know that you can use networkx for this kind of stuff, I saw a QA recently with a good answer, I'm looking fo rit

Comment: It was likely asked by me :P, I've been trying multiple ways to figure out this problem and it seems that networkx is overkill

Comment: The issue I had been running into before is when I try to build a network around say `A,1` it will group everything related to `A` and `1` so if I had `Z,1`->`F,3` it would include that in the group which would be incorrect :(

Comment: @MaxB but here I tried with N,1 instead of N,14 and it i snot grouped with A,1 so I guess it is ok :)

Comment: Hmm I see, i'll play around with it I must be missing something.. Thanks again :)